# Going from Spring 3 to Spring 2 what to keep in mind?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've been told I have to develop a Spring 2 application (no idea myself why they don't want a Spring 3 application since they use Java 5).
The problem is that all my experience is with Spring 3.

I know there's a reference manual but I find that those are a lot easier when moving forward and not backward.

So I was wondering what the major differences are between these 2.
I'm expecting to have to do a lot more configuration work in xmls.

In Spring 3 I mostly use the `@RequestMapping`, `@ModelMapping`, path binding in the jsp, automatic type conversion from String to date, hibernate-validator, ...

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Did they give any reasons for wanting to stick with Spring 2?

Comment: Bozho, wasn't sure but I managed to get a hold of a coworker and while he isn't sure he thinks it's 2.5.6. And reason: slow adapters. I guess they are a bit wary "new" versions because they think they're buggy. And I'm pretty junior so getting them to update...

Comment: spring 3 is just a little upgrade over 2.5.6 - some bugfixes, and some new functionality. Apart from that it's the same. I would strongly advise insisting on 3.0. We migrated our production system from 2.5 to 3.0 without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you haven't been given a reason for using Spring 2, can't you find out what that reason is? They may not be aware of Spring 3's existence. It can't hurt to ask, especially if you tell them you're more proficient in Spring 3.

Failing that, then most of the features you've mentioned work OK in Spring 2.5.6 (including annotation-based MVC, form tags), with the notable exception of the Hibernate Validator integration. You'll have to use the other validation techniques mentioned in the [ref manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/) instead.

Most of the Spring 3 new stuff was really under the covers, with much of the infrastructure rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

I belive the [REST support stuff was new in Spring 3.0](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/). So you will not be able to bind a path variable to an method variable

```
//Spring 3.0
@RequestMapping("/customer/{id}/logoContent")
public void getCustomer(@PathVariable("id") final Customer customer) {...}
```

An additional source of the major changed between Spring 2.5 and Spring 3.0 could be the [Spring Blog](http://blog.springsource.com/category/spring/30/). This blog has a lot of posts showing the new features of Spring 3.0 (autumn of 2009 till middle of 2010). -- So this post can give you a hint what possible is not so easy in 2.5.

In my personal opinion the major different between Spring 2 and Spring 3 was the shift of configuration from Xml (Spring 2) to Annotations (Spring 3).

BTW: You should check if there is still a security/bug support for spring 2!